# Coordinate form of divergence of anti-symmetric tensor field

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation

just a quick question on something that might save me a little bit of time and effort. In a general curved metric, the divergence of a vector field, $A^\mu$, can be written as:

$$ \nabla_\mu A^\mu = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_\mu\left(\sqrt{-g}A^\mu\right). $$

likewise, the divergence of a totally anti-symmetric rank $ \left(^2_0\right) $ tensor field, $F^{\mu\nu}$, can be written as:

$$ \nabla_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_\mu\left(\sqrt{-g}F^{\mu\nu}\right). $$

My question is whether or not there exists an equally simple coordinate form for the divergence of a totally anti-symmetric rank $ \left(^0_2\right) $ tensor:

$$ \nabla^\mu F_{\mu\nu} =  ?$$

I tried to derive an expression, but I was left with two non-canceling terms of the form:

$$\nabla^\mu \left(F_{\mu\nu}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\right) =  g^{\sigma\mu}\partial_\sigma\left(F_{\mu\nu}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\right) +\frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}} g^{am}g^{bn}\left(F_{a\nu}\partial_bg_{mn}+F_{ba}\partial_ng_{m\nu}\right).$$

Since I am doing this by hand, it is very possible that I made several silly error in this derivation. Its also possible that there just isn't a simple expression.

Comment: How is this a physics question?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by simple? How about

$$
\nabla^\mu F_{\mu\nu} = g_{\nu\rho} \nabla_\mu F^{\mu\rho} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g} }g_{\nu\rho} \partial_\mu \left( \sqrt{g} g^{\mu\alpha} g^{\rho\beta} F_{\alpha\beta} \right)
$$

PS - A simple expression exists for the divergence of a rank $(1,0)$ and $(2,0)$  tensor since we can write
$$
\nabla_\mu V^\mu = \ast d \ast V~, \qquad \nabla_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = \left( \ast d  \ast F    \right)^\nu
$$
In fact for the same reason nice expressions will exist for $(n,0)$ antisymmetric tensors.

Comment: Simple as in requiring the smallest possible number of contractions and derivative terms. I am doing some work involving simulating the electrovacuum and multiple contractions quickly rack up the simulation expense.

Comment: OK. I've given you the general reasons why it works well in those case and not in others.